# Describe the condition of "non-adjacent 3-cycles" in terms of the cubic adjacency matrix

Tags: planar-graphs, graph-colouring

> [Oleg Borodin and André Raspaud](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009589560300025X)
>   "A sufficient condition for planar graphs to be 3-colorable"
>   Journal of Combinatorial Theory B88, 2003, 17–27

state the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture 1.2:**
>   Every planar graph without adjacent 3-cycles and 5-cycles is 3-colorable.

My question is whether it is possible to describe this condition of "non-adjacent 3-cycles" purely in terms of the cubic adjacency matrix?